# How to show array list in dropdown option

Tags: javascript, arrays

after many types trying and search on google now i have no option to ask here..

my question is i want to show data in select option dropdown menu.. the date is json array list..

here is my code

```
<select name="" id="state_list">
     <option>select state</option>
</select>



<script>      
var url = "#";

    function getData() {
      fetch(url)
        .then((data) => {
          return data.json();
        })
        .then((covidData) => {

          var dropdown = document.getElementById("state_list");
          var stateList = covidData.data.regional;

     for (i = 0; i < stateList.lenght; i++) {
         dropdown[dropdown.lenght] = new Option(stateList[i],stateList[i]); 
    }
     })
 </script>
```

Comment: Hello, you should maybe try to create a new option element for each item in your list and then append the options element to your select 
You can use document.createElement('option'), then set the attributes (value and the option itself) and then append it to your select

Comment: You have a type in `lenght`. Rest is correct.

Comment: but the api data in not showing

Comment: Well, you also have to call the function at one point.

Comment: You should delete this question since it mostly bases upon two typos of `length`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below to populate your `stateList` to your drop-down.

```
var select = document.getElementById("state_list"); 
for(var i = 0; i < stateList.length; i++) {
    var opt = stateList[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}​
```

A working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/shyntz0o/1/

Comment: working in fiddle using simple array but not working using api link

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `lenght` and did not close the function correctly (missing the final `}`). Also your option appending logic does not work out (again because of the typo `lenght`).

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var url = "https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest";

  function getData(){
    fetch(url)
      .then((data) => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then((covidData) => {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("state_list");
        var stateList = covidData.data.regional;

        for(var i=0; i<stateList.length; i++){
           dropdown.appendChild(new Option(stateList[i].loc, stateList[i].loc))
        }
      })
   };

   getData()
 }
```

```html
<select name="" id="state_list">
     <option>select state</option>
</select>
```